# Galleria dynamic Javascript/jQuery issue in Plone

Tags: javascript, slider, plone, galleria, theming

So here's the deal. I had a lot of trouble with the true gallery in plone so I bought the Galleria Slideshow with the Twelve Theme.
I did the normal stuff to run Galleria but now there's a problem.

This is the HTML section:

```
<div id="content"> 
    <!-- GALLERIA -->
    <div id="galleria">
    </div>
    <!-- /GALLERIA -->
</div>
```

With this rule, I grap all the links with images and put them into my galleria DIV:

```
<replace css:content=".item a" css:theme-children="#galleria" />
```

So this is the Result of this operation:

```
<!-- GALLERIA -->
    <div id="galleria">
        <a href="...">
            <img src="..." />
        </a>
        <a href="...">
            <img src="..." />
        </a>
        <a href="...">
            <img src="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
<!-- /GALLERIA -->
```

So here's the problem.
Although all js and css files from galleria are successfully loaded, nothing happens. Galleria should put some divs around the images to create the slideshow.

Javascript is turned on. jQuery is working.

Is there anyone who has an idea why this does not work in plone?

EDIT: Chrome drops this error message in his console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /http://localhost:8080/lox/home/++theme++lox.responsive/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.css/: Nothing to repeat galleria-1.2.9.js:847
(anonymous function) galleria-1.2.9.js:847
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:648
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:270
Utils.loadCSS galleria-1.2.9.js:846
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: What was the problem you had with plonetruegallery? I'm the author and have used it successfully with many projects as have others.

Comment: Other things: any js errors in the console? Where's your galleria js code to startup the gallery? What is the css that you're using? You sure the galleria resources are referenced correctly? Galleria requires you to define a height of the gallery container somewhere. Did you do that? It'd help if you either gave an example site to show where it's not working or pasted the code you're using to wire up galleria.

Comment: the problem i had was that the customer wanted the twelve theme on his galleria slideshow. I didn't found out how to implement a new theme to plonetruegallery. Then i wanted to code it by myself but it was to complex to make just some quick changes. So I decided to put the slideshow static into the index site of my plone theme. But nothing happens.

I will make a new buildout and post a link to the site as soon as possible.

Comment: Look at collective.ptg.galleria. Very simple to customize galleries.

Comment: From the js error, it can't load the theme css file and that's why it's failing.

Comment: and a shameless plug: http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849696608/?tag=packtpubli-20

Answer (score 0):

Turning THIS:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').each(function() {
    if ( new RegExp( href ).test( this.href ) ) {
        link = this;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Into THIS:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').each(function() {
    /*if ( new RegExp( href ).test( this.href ) ) {
        link = this;
        return false;
    }*/
    return false;
});
```

Made the deal. :)

Comment: Are you privileged to accept your answer? That would be cool, in order to have a better distinction between answered and unanswered quests, TIA.